# SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0 in Angular2 when try to store in local storage

Tags: json, angular, local-storage

I have a json response like this.

```
   {
  "response": {
    "data": {
      "name": "ABC",
      "Id": "1234",
      "address": "adthhyrr"    
    }
  }
}
```

In service.ts I am doing a request like this to get the response data.

```
 public getResponseData() : Promise<any> {
      if(typeof(this.login_data) === "undefined") {
            return this.http.get('assets/response.json')
            .toPromise().then(res => {
                                  this.login_data = res.json().response.data;

                                  return this.login_data;
                }).catch(this.handleError);
      } else {
          return Promise.resolve(this.login_data);
      }
}
```

And I am storing the login_data in localstorage like this

```
  getAllData() {  
    if (localStorage.getItem('login_data') === null || localStorage.getItem('login_data') === undefined) {  
      localStorage.setItem('login_data', JSON.stringify(this.login_data)); 
      return this.login_data;  
    }  
    else {  
      var login_data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('login_data'));  
      return login_data;  
    }  

  }
```

And in component.ts class I am getting data like this

```
   this.logindata = this.myservice.getAllData();
```

But while doing this I am getting this error.
**SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0**.

**But if i am not storing in localstorage then i am doing like this in service.**

public getAllData(): any {

```
return this.login_data;
```

}

And in component.ts file i am getting data by calling this method.

```
 this.logindata = this.myservice.getAllData();
```

And here it is working fine.But when i am trying to store data into localstorage and want to fetch from local storage i am getting this error.
**SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0**

Can anyone please tell me where exactly i am doing wrong.

Comment: Could you put `console.log(this.login_data);console.log(localStorage.getItem('login_data'));` in the beginning of `getAllData()` method and post the result. Error is coming from `var login_data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('login_data'));` or `JSON.stringify(this.login_data)` we need to figure out what is the problem with this JSON

Comment: Okay I see that you say that error is thrown only when getting data from `localStorage` then this `var login_data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('login_data'));` should be the problematic code, could you `console.log(localStorage.getItem('login_data'))`?

Comment: try `var login_data = localStorage.getItem('login_data');`

Comment: I tried with this console.log(localStorage.getItem('login_data'))
before var login_data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('login_data'));  this line. And its showing undefined @codtex

Comment: what result you are getting from `console.log(localStorage.getItem('login_data'))`

Comment: Look in the browser storage using the browser debug tool and verify your values are stored as valid JSON. They should be strings that are either `{} ` or `[] `. You seem to have string values that are not valid JSON.

Comment: I am not getting any result from console.log(localStorage.getItem('login_data')).
Its showing undefined.@Sravan

Comment: so if it is undefined it shouldnot go to else block, so you have your `if` condition not working, check the answer once. @ananya

Answer (score 0):

The error  `SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0` says that you are **trying to parse an object to object which is not possible**.

So, while retrieving from `localStorage` check the type and parse if it is not an `object`

Also change the if condition to,
`if ( !(localStorage.getItem('login_data'))) {`

```
 getAllData() {
    var data = localStorage.getItem('login_data');
  if (!data) {
    localStorage.setItem('login_data', JSON.stringify(this.login_data));
    return this.login_data;
  } else {
      var login_data;
      if(typeof data == 'object')
        {
            login_data = data;
        }else{
            login_data = JSON.parse(data);


        }
        return login_data;
  }
}
```

Comment: while keeping this code am getting this compile time error.
[ts] Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'login_data' must be of type 'string', but here has type 'any'..
In this else part.
else{
            var login_data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('login_data'));


        }
@Sravan

Comment: Did you also tried with `if ( !localStorage.getItem('login_data'))`, I think that one pair of brackets is redundant, anyway your solution should work

Comment: @codtex, the bracket is not redundant, i added it intentionally to be more clearer on that line.

Comment: Also since you started to write this code, could you please improve it to look more professional and store `localStorage.getItem('login_data')` inside a variable and work with that variable down in the code

Comment: Yes i tried with if ( !localStorage.getItem('login_data')).But no luck.Getting same error.@codtex , @Sravan

Comment: Beautiful, much better :)))

Comment: I tried with the updated code.still getting same error.And getting error in this else part.
else{
            login_data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('login_data'));
  } @Sravan

Comment: have you taken the type of `login_data` as a string in any component?, if yes try changing it to `any`

Comment: or change the name of `login_data` to something else.

Comment: No i have not taken the type of login_data as string anywhere.@ Sravan

Comment: do you have any service for `localStorage`?

Comment: No i am using directly localstorage provided by angular2.@Sravan

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153948/discussion-between-sravan-and-ananya).